# Boost beast websocket server async accept failed, buffer overflow

Tags: http, websocket, boost-asio, boost-beast

I wrote a websocket server thru boost asio websocket.
When I try to connect it with chrome, it always said connect failed. 
And log shows that buffer overflow. 
Especially after I open lots of website.

[2019-06-21 16:40:45.071345]-[0x00003130]-[error]:[NormalSession.cpp:75] acceptor async accept failed, ec = beast.http:7, msg = buffer overflow

```
void NormalSession::run() {
    auto sp = shared_from_this();
    ws_->async_accept(boost::asio::bind_executor(*strand_, [&,sp](boost::system::error_code ec) {
        if (ec) {
            LOG_ERR << "acceptor async accept failed, ec = " << ec<<", msg = "<<ec.message();
            return;
        }

        process();
    }));

}
```

```
var ws=new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:12802");
ws.onopen=()=>{console.log('ws open')};
ws.onclose=()=>{console.log('ws close')};
ws.onmessage=(msg)=>{console.log('ws onMessage');console.log(msg)};
```

So why the buffer is overflow? And how to resolve it ?

---

The full code

iListener.h

```
class iListener: public std::enable_shared_from_this<iListener>  {
public:

    iListener(const std::string &, unsigned short , boost::asio::io_context& );

    ~iListener();

public:
    void run();
protected:

    virtual void do_accept()=0;

protected:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor *acceptor_=NULL;
};
```

iListener.cpp

```
iListener::iListener(const std::string &addressStr, unsigned short port, boost::asio::io_context &ioc) {

    acceptor_ = NULL;


    auto const address = boost::asio::ip::make_address(addressStr);

    acceptor_ = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(ioc);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint{address, port};
    boost::system::error_code ec;

    // Open the acceptor
    acceptor_->open(endpoint.protocol(), ec);
    if (ec) {
        LOG_ERR << "acceptor open failed, ec = " << ec << ", msg = " << ec.message();
        return;

    }

    // Allow address reuse
    acceptor_->set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true), ec);
    if (ec) {
        LOG_ERR << "acceptor set option failed, ec = " << ec << ", msg = " << ec.message();
        return;
    }

    // Bind to the server address
    acceptor_->bind(endpoint, ec);
    if (ec) {
        LOG_ERR << "acceptor bind failed, ec = " << ec << ", msg = " << ec.message();
        return;
    }

    // Start listening for connections
    acceptor_->listen(boost::asio::socket_base::max_listen_connections, ec);
    if (ec) {
        LOG_ERR << "acceptor listen failed, ec = " << ec << ", msg = " << ec.message();
        return;
    }

}

iListener::~iListener() {
    delete acceptor_;
    acceptor_ = NULL;
}

void iListener::run() {
    if (!acceptor_->is_open()) {
        return;
    }
    do_accept();

}
```

NormalListener.h

```
class NormalListener:public iListener {
public:
    NormalListener(const std::string &addressStr, unsigned short port, boost::asio::io_context& ioc);
    ~NormalListener();
private:
    void do_accept();
private:
};
```

NormalListener.cpp

```
NormalListener::NormalListener(const std::string &addressStr, unsigned short port,  boost::asio::io_context& ioc):iListener(addressStr, port, ioc) {


}

NormalListener::~NormalListener() {

}


void NormalListener::do_accept() {
    auto sp = shared_from_this();
    acceptor_->async_accept([&,sp](const boost::system::error_code& ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket peer) {
        if (ec) {
            LOG_ERR << "acceptor async accept failed, ec = " << ec<<", msg = "<<ec.message();
            return;
        }
        else {
            // Create the session and run it
            std::make_shared<NormalSession>(std::move(peer))->run();

        }
        do_accept();
    });
}
```

iSession.hpp

```
template<typename T>
class iSession : public std::enable_shared_from_this<iSession<T>> {

public:
    iSession() {
        ws_ = NULL;
        strand_ = NULL;
        buffer_ = new boost::beast::multi_buffer();
    }

    ~iSession() {
        delete buffer_;
        buffer_ = NULL;
        delete strand_;
        strand_ = NULL;
        delete ws_;
        ws_ = NULL;

    }

public:
    boost::beast::websocket::stream<T> *ws_ = NULL;
    boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> *strand_ = NULL;
    boost::beast::multi_buffer *buffer_ = NULL;


public:
    void virtual run() = 0;

protected:
    void process() {       
    }



private:


protected:

};

#endif //ESDK_MSP_ISESSION_HPP
```

NormalSession.h

```
class NormalSession : public iSession<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> {
public:
    NormalSession(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket);

    ~NormalSession();

public:
    void run();

protected:

};
```

NormalSession.cpp

```
NormalSession::NormalSession(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket){
    ws_ = new boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(std::move(socket));
    strand_ = new boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type>(ws_->get_executor());
}

NormalSession::~NormalSession() {

}

void NormalSession::run() {
    auto sp = shared_from_this();
    ws_->async_accept(boost::asio::bind_executor(*strand_, [&,sp](boost::system::error_code ec) {
        if (ec) {
            LOG_ERR << "acceptor async accept failed, ec = " << ec<<", msg = "<<ec.message();
            return;
        }

        process();
    }));

}
```

Comment: where is buffer in the code you've posted? post the full-code (or a mock of it )

Comment: @Explorer_N  Sorry for reply you too late, I have not set the buffer..  pls see code I edit right now.

Comment: Before that, I think you need to correct the tittle, because I don't think there is such a thing called "Boost asio websocket". I figured out you are using Boost.Beast. @vainman

Comment: And one other thing that bugs me is, why do accept throw "buffer Overflow", do you think accept requires Buffer?

Comment: @Explorer_N I've got no idea, might be the http buffer?  need CA from chrome?

Comment: you are calling  `process()` after accept in one implementation, you sure, completion handlers of successful accept is not using  any buffer?

Comment: @Explorer_N No, just parse the message from client, and the error code is throw during  async_accept , not yet process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the documentation:

> If the request size exceeds the capacity of the stream's internal
>   buffer, the error `websocket::buffer_overflow` will be indicated. To
>   handle larger requests, an application should read the HTTP request
>   directly using `http::async_read` and then pass the request to the
>   appropriate overload of `websocket::stream::accept` or
>   `websocket::stream::async_accept`

See:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream/async_accept/overload1.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I try to use http::async_read, there are always error_code 995, the IO thread has been exited. Is there any sample or suggestion?

Comment: Now I use http::async_read and websocket::stream::async_accept ,it works well in ws, but   it not working in wss. How to use it in wss?

Comment: yep,finally I found the solution, thank you for your hint

Comment: @vainman I am facing the similar issue. Can you please tell how did you solve the issue?

Comment: @vainman Can you please tell how did you fix the issue?